# 500 error getting Teams Channel Messages (MS-Graph Beta)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I've been using the Beta API of Graph to manipulate messages in Teams.  On 10/16, I began getting errors performing these operations.  I finally tracked it down to getting 500 messages on any API call in

GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages

The same call, omitting the `/messages` returns the channel info correctly.

For instance

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod "https://graph.microsoft.us/beta/teams/$teamID/channels/$chanID/" -Method Get -Headers $head
```

Returns a channel entity object, but

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod "https://graph.microsoft.us/beta/teams/$teamID/channels/$chanID/messages" -Method Get -Headers $head
```

return the below error (full data from fiddler)

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 83ef77bb-5fa5-4277-939d-c192e7900c0e
client-request-id: 83ef77bb-5fa5-4277-939d-c192e7900c0e
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"USGov Iowa","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_3"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2019 18:33:43 GMT
Content-Length: 231

{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Failed to execute request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "83ef77bb-5fa5-4277-939d-c192e7900c0e",
      "date": "2019-10-23T18:33:43"
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I am in the GCC High environment.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Hey! Formulating an actual question in the body of your post might give the community a better chance to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Application permissions? If so, this endpoint as well as most of the other messages endpoints (other than send message) fall under the Protected APIs within teams, therefore you'll need to apply for access to use these API's.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis

Comment: This isn't an API permissions issue, unless MS changed the permissions from whats documented. It was working up until the 16th of this month.

Also, as an aside, our Flow workflows stopped posting Teams messages at about the same time.